# Nativescript: multiple environment configurations

Tags: nativescript

We have several API's, one for each of our customers, and I want to be able to create apps for all of these (different AppResources). These apps will have their own logo's, titles, app IDs etc. Also, if possible, I want to be able to swap these post build, so that we can set up a build-once, deploy-many automation tool. The necessary files would ideally be fetched from the API itself. How would I go about and do this?

Comment: There is a feature request logged for this on the NativeScript CLI repository: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3156 You can track the progress of the request there.

Comment: Not completely the same though, because that's build time, not deploy time. Still relevant though, thanks.

Comment: You can use apk-tool to unzip a built android application, then change its resources, and pack it again. This is useful for CI and testing. However I do not recommend this practice to release apps and change resources dynamically in apps that will get to the end user.